# IOS Socket Io refusing to connect

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, safari

On Chrome on my PC it all connections without a problem however on mobile it doesn't work and I haven't got a apple computer to open developer tools. I don't own the full domain it is being hosted on I only have a subdomain on it. If you need to see anymore code or information I am happy to give them. Any Ideas?

```
var socket = io();
```

Comment: Is the mobile connected on your WiFi on your local network or connected via the cellular network?  Where is the server?  Is it on your local network or in a hosting facility with general internet access?

Comment: Have you added event handlers for all the possible client-side socket.io errors and logged those?

Comment: The server is running on heroku so the WiFi the phone is on should matter and how would I go about adding event handlers for client-side socket.io errors?

Comment: socket.io errors are just events you listen for.  See [this part of the doc](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect-error%E2%80%99-1).